# Oracle 11g. Inner joins. Table /view does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

Just trying to teach myself some basics. I keep getting the error table/view does not exist when trying to run a basic inner join

```
SELECT c.cus_code, c.cus_lname, c.cus_fname, i.inv_number
FROM customer c,
INNER JOIN invoice i
ON i.cus_code = c.cus_code;


--ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 11-
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This is exactly what stack overflow was met for.

Answer (score 4):

Error is due to comma after `customer c`. It should be:

```
SELECT c.cus_code, c.cus_lname, c.cus_fname, i.inv_number
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN invoice i
ON i.cus_code = c.cus_code
```